# Are simple enum types as efficient as integer constants?

Tags: java

When you use an `enum` type, you have the ability to add arguments to each constant, provide a body for each constant, and provide a body for the type.  But if you don't do any of that:

```
enum enumType { C1, C2, C3 };
```

is it as efficient to use the `enum` type as it would be just to declare integer constants?

```
static final int C1 = 1;
static final int C2 = 2;
static final int C3 = 3;  // or whatever
```

Or is there still some overhead due to this feature (the ability to provide bodies), even though the feature isn't being used in this case?

Comment: Enums should have some overhead, due to them being a toned-down object.  Its like having an Integer object vs a plain old int.

Comment: Is the "overhead" worth losing little things like type safety?

Comment: @MrTi There is nothing toned-down about `enum` members: they are full-fledged objects with arbitrary fields and methods, and each member can even be an instance of its own class (anonymous subclass of the main enum type).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, enum constants are objects.  However it is not correct to regard them as being just like any object.  Enum constants are guaranteed to be static and final.  They are immutable and therefore automatically thread safe.  Finally, the JVM guarantees that they are singletons and are therefore safer to use than other serialized objects which may be vulnerable to a variety of attacks without special care, esp. if only a single instance must ever exist.

Comment: @scottb Immutable, you say? Well, play with this: `public enum X { Y; public int a; }` Another point, I said they were "full-fledged". Do you not agree with that characterization? Are there any limitations on the instance members of enum objects? The only limitation that I am aware of is on the *constructors*, which is the means by which the instance count is tigtly regulated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't specify any kind of context within which the performance should be compared. In most cases the fact that `enum` members are objects is completely irrelevant because only the reference values are being compared; the objects themselves are not even touched.

*However*, `public static final int` are *compile-time constants*, and their values are hardcoded at the place of usage, which clearly imposes no overhead at all.

So it's very little overhead against no overhead at all, but at the expense of problems with compile-time constants, such that changing any of them requires recompiling everything which references it.

Comment: Good point about the irrelevancy of the enum members being objects; I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very efficient to use `enum`s. You can even compare two instances of an enum using `==`, with the added benefit of type safety:

```
Fruits.APPLES == Fruits.ORANGES
```

If you look inside the `Enum` class, you'll see that the `equals()` method uses `==` to compare two instances. And all the heavy lifting of creating enum instances is done at class compilation time, so there's no additional overhead there.

Answer (score 1):

Enum constants offer no appreciable performance penalty when compared to using `static final int` constants to achieve related functionality.  Internally, an enum constant is simply represented as a 32-bit integer.  In the context of the JVM, however, an enum constant offers type safety, extensibility, and far more flexibility than you can achieve with int constants.

The only downside to using enum constants over int constants is the time to load and initialize the enum class objects, however this is unlikely to be appreciable in any real world scenario.  In the example you give in your question, once the application is loaded and running, there would be no performance penalty for using enums over int constants.  Note also that because enum constants are necessarily singletons (guaranteed by the JVM), they may be efficiently compared with the '==' operator for both equality and identity just as you would do with most primitive values.

Joshua Bloch provides an excellent discussion of enum types in Effective Java, 2nd Ed. and makes compelling arguments why enum constants should always be used to express any fixed(or even mostly fixed) set of constants that are known at compile time.

Comment: Yes, I think using enums is preferable for readability and type safety.  One thing I just found out, though: you can't declare one inside a method.  So if your method uses an algorithm that could be in different states, and you'd like to use an `enum` to represent the current state, you can't declare the `enum` inside the method.  You have to move it outside, which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It solely depends on the context in which they are being used. As if you have some related constants then you should use enums and if not then you should use constants. As it is illogical and wrong way to club irrelevant constants together.

Both are inline constants, i.e. that each occurrence of both of them are replaced with their corresponding values and so whenever you made changes to them, you should compile all of the files again, which used them in their code. Otherwise you will get incorrect results.

If you have relevant constants then using enums will be a smart choice. As,

1. They are serialized.
2. There is API support provided so that u can use them efficiently and without much overhead.

Comment: No, `enum` members are not compile-time constants. Check the JLS.